# Set size of bitset at the running moment

Tags: c++, stl

I have simple class with width and height member fields which define number of rows and columns in matrix. I have matrix representation (0nly 0 and 1 needed) like **bitset<> fields** ( I included ) and I want to set size of bitset field in constructor.

```
Matrix(int w, int h)
{
    // fields to have size w*h
}

private:
    int width;
    int height;
    //bitset<unknown at the moment> fields;
```

Is possible to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` does exactly what you need, with 1 bit per value.

Alternatively you can use `boost::dynamic_bitset` (I think it was called).

Comment: Note that this is an allowed, but not required optimiztation to store each bool in one bit.

Comment: @PlasmaHH is trolling. C++11 §2.37/2 "operations dealing with the bool value type map to bit values in the container storage and allocator_traits::construct (20.6.8.2) is not used to construct these values". An implementation is technically allowed to store each bit in one separate `bool` value, but since that's absurd it's not a consideration for practical programming.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) from boost to achieve this.

Comment: @gahhcep it all depends on what the OP is trying to accomplish.